# How to match more than one rows using INNER JOIN with MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by

What is the right way to select films which labels are 'Action' AND 'Drama' using INNER JOIN ?

I've tried this query, the result must be 'Taken, The Godfather' but, no result returned.

```
SELECT 
    f.film_guid,
    f.film_name
FROM
    films as f
INNER JOIN
    film_labels as l ON l.film_guid = f.film_guid
WHERE
    l.label = 'Action' AND l.label = 'Drama'
```

### Table: films

```
+------------+----------------+
| film_guid  | film_name      |
+------------+----------------+
| filmguid_1 | Taken          |
| filmguid_2 | Matrix         |
| filmguid_3 | The Godfather  |
+------------+----------------+
```

### Table: film_labels

```
+------------+----------------+
| film_guid  | label          |
+------------+----------------+
| filmguid_1 | Action         |
| filmguid_1 | Drama          |
| filmguid_1 | Family         |
| filmguid_2 | Action         |
| filmguid_3 | Action         |
| filmguid_3 | Drama          |
+------------+----------------+
```

Comment: OR not AND..This is quite a fundamental thing to get on top of

Comment: I knot that AND wont work. This is why I'm asking the right way to select both Action and Drama.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for a rows in `film_labels` that contains both Action and Drama, which cannot happen. You need to search *across* labels that correspond to the given film, which suggest aggregation:

```
SELECT f.film_guid, f.film_name
FROM films as f
INNER JOIN film_labels as l ON l.film_guid = f.film_guid
WHERE l.label IN ('Action', 'Drama')  -- either one, or the other
GROUP BY f.film_guid, f.film_name
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2                   -- both match
```

Note that you could also use `exists` with correlated subquery. It is a bit longer to type but *could* be more efficient (with the right indexes in place), since it avoids the need for aggregation:

```
SELECT f.*
FROM films as f
WHERE
    EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM film_labels l WHERE l.film_guid = f.film_guid AND l.label = 'Action')
    AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM film_labels l WHERE l.film_guid = f.film_guid AND l.label = 'Drama')
```

For performance with the second query, you want an index on `film_labels(film_guid , label)`.

Comment: The first example is more flexible if more labels are needed. For example, if a film must have all three labels (Action, Drama, and Family), you would only have to add 'Family' to the `IN` clause and change the count to 3 like so:
`WHERE l.label IN ('Action', 'Drama', 'Family')
GROUP BY f.film_guid, f.film_name
HAVING COUNT(*) = 3` . This is more useful in scenarios where your labels are variable.

Comment: I used to store the labels in films table as combined like 'Action,Drama' and search them with LIKE query. As you know that this is not the efficient way to search labels. Because of this, i decided to move the labels to another table and search them with INNER JOIN. IF @GMB 's approaches are faster than LIKE query, i will change my queries. OR, do you have a better idea to store and search the labels?

Comment: I would go with GMB's first solution.

Comment: You're on the right track with storing the labels in a separate table.

Comment: I've tried the first solution with 150 K+ data, is much slower than the LIKE queries.
First solution takes 1.2 seconds to complete (With indexes.), LIKE takes only .2 seconds.

Comment: @one_developer: did you try the second solution as well (with the suggested index)?

Comment: @GMB, sorry for the late response. You won't believe that it took more than 30seconds. And connection timeout. I'm using LIMIT 24 btw.